# Make a StackPanel Orientation Horizontal in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this `xaml` code in a `View`

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="I am IRON" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MeasuringDeviceCommunicators}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>              
            <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

The `ItemSource` of the `ListView` is bound to a `List` in my `ViewModel` (as shown in the code)

When I run the application all my `TextBlocks` are shown vertically even though I have set the `Orientation` of the inner StackPanel to `Horizontal`.

Comment: Try it out WrapPanel rather than StackPanel at inner side

Comment: @RameshMuthiah It didn't work :( BTW I am really new to WPF and XAML

Comment: I hope @Cédric Bignon solution might help you. Please try it out

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To change the layout of a `ListView`, use the [`ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) property:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="I am IRON" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MeasuringDeviceCommunicators}"  >
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <!-- Here is the panel that will contain the items -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Your item Template is here -->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

You also may want to use a [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.aspx) instead of `StackPanel`, it may improve performance (if you have lot of items to show).

### Update

If you want to add a list in each item of your stack panel, you can do it by modifying the `ItemTemplate` (which represents how each item is displayed).

For example:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>

             <!-- Displays the tags (or whatever you want) -->
            <ListView Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"/>
        <Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

To sum up, the `ListView` has 3 interesting properties to define how it is rendered:

- [`ItemsControl.ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) : Represents how the items in the list are rendered
- [`ItemsControl.ItemsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel.aspx) : Represents the layout of the list (the position and size of the items in the list). You can use `StackPanel`, `VirtualizingStackPanel`, `WrapPanel`, ...
- [`Control.Template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.template.aspx) : Represents how the whole list is rendered

Here is a code using all these properties:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Items>
        <Button Content="Button 1"/>
        <Button Content="Button 2"/>
        <Button Content="Button 3"/>
        <Button Content="Button 4"/>
    </ListView.Items>

    <!-- The layout of the list (position and size of the elements -->
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <!-- StackPanel means : the elements are rendered in stack, either horizontally or vertically (the way it is rendered in StackPanel is defined in code -->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightCoral"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- How I want the list to look like? -->
    <ListView.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <!-- A blue background with a green border -->
            <Border Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" BorderThickness="5">
                <!-- ItemsPresenter "represents" the ItemsPanel defined above -->
                <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ListView.Template>

    <!-- How I want each item to look like? -->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <!-- A "This is an item:" label followed by the item itself --> 
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="This is an item : "/>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Note, this part:

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightCoral"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
<ListView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" BorderThickness="5">
            <ItemsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListView.Template>
```

is equivalent to:

```
<ListView.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Border Background="LightBlue" BorderBrush="DarkGreen" BorderThickness="5">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="LightCoral"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ListView.Template>
```

Comment: Using this will remove visualization but only really issue if you showing a lot of items

Comment: @MarkHomer I updated my post few seconds before you wrote your remark. ;)

Comment: Wow It worked. Thanks. But I am very sad Because I don't know how can I learn these things. For me who has worked with `Winforms` it is somehow wired. @CédricBignon which book or reference do you suggest to learn WPF?

Comment: @MehrdadKamelzadeh I've never read any book in programming... To learn those things, Internet is a very useful place. Stackoverflow too. I'm pretty sure most of the questions you will have have already been answered on this website.

Comment: @CédricBignon Sorry If this a silly question. But what if I want to add a new list inside each `TextBlock`?

Comment: In addition to what Cédric has posted (I agree at all), I'd recommend to set the IsItemsHost="true" in the (Stack)Panel inside the ItemsPanelTemplate.

Comment: @MarioVernari `IsItemsHost = "true"` is needed if the `StackPanel` is defined in the `ListView.ControlTemplate`. It is not needed when it is set in the `ItemsPanel`.

Comment: @MarioVernari What is its advantages? what does it do?

Comment: I must admit that I didn't know about the uselessly setting when in the ItemsPanelTemplate: I always set for the target panel.
Thanks Cèdric!

@Mehrad: It needs for the items generator to know ehere the item containers have to be attached. The internal engine seek for this property in order to find the target panel.

Comment: @CédricBignon - it works, but cannot select the list item anymore.